# Django template inheritance the other way round

Tags: django-templates

Django template system lets you easily specify a template and fill it with different data using `extends` and `block`s.

What I need to do is to have several templates, filled with the same data (`block`s) while avoiding code repetition. It sounds like a usecase for templatetags but consider this example:

> ```
> <div class="container">
>     {% get_tags page as tags %}
>     {% if tags %}
>         <div class="ribbon">
>             <span class="ribbon-inner">{{ tags|join:' | ' }}</span>
>         </div>
>     {% endif %}   
> </div>
> ```

If I wanted to display the tags in another template using a different html elements/classes I would have to create at least two templatetags (has_tags and get_tags) or include html in templatetags code.

I'd like to have something like this:

```
#common.html
{% block tags %}
    {% get_tags page as tags %}
    {% if tags %}
        <div class="ribbon">
            <span class="ribbon-inner">{{ tags|join:' | ' }}</span>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

#template_A.html
{% include common.html %}
<div class="container-1">
    {% block tags %}
        {{ block.super }}
    {% endblock %}
</div>

#template_B.html
{% include common.html %}
{% block tags %}
    {% get_tags page as tags %}
    {{ tags|join:', ' }}
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is that include renders the template first, therefore it doesn't work this way. There are a lot of similar points in the file I'm editing, so creating and including template for each of them is not a great solution either.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is my solution:

```
#templateA.html
{% include "_common.html" with parent_file="_templateA.html" %}

#templateB.html
{% include "_common.html" with parent_file="_templateB.html" %}

#_templateA.html
<i>{% block tags %}{% endblock %}</i>

#_templateB.html
<b>{% block tags %}{{ tags|join:' & ' }}{% endblock %}</b>

#_common.html
{% extends parent_file %}
{% block tags %}
    {% if not block.super %}  # this does the trick
        {{ tags|join:' I ' }}
    {% else %}
        {{ block.super }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

This allows having HTML templates in _templateA.html and _templateB.html. If the block is left empty, it is filled with default from _common.html, while it can be overriden in _template.

It would be nice to override the `block` tag to avoid code repetition in _common.html but the following implementation fails on block.super() because of missing context.

```
@register.tag('overridable_block')
def overridable_block(parser, token):
    from django.template.loader_tags import do_block
    block = do_block(parser, token)
    if block.super():
        return block.parent
    return block
```

Haven't found a way past this yet.